# Directly adding textures to Assets<Texture> resource causes a gpu_alloc error

Tags: rust, bevy

I'm loading textures from a file as a `Vec<u8>` and turning that data into a Texture, when I add that texture to the Asset resource to get a `Handle<Texture>` it causes two errors, the first one comes from the logging system and says `gpu_alloc::block: Memory block wasn't deallocated` the second one (which I'm assuming is related) is `thread 'main' panicked at 'range end index 32896 out of range for slice of length 32768'`. This all seems to stem from this code block

```
                 Ok(pak) => {
                    let mut assets : CurrentlyLoadedAssets = CurrentlyLoadedAssets::default();
                    for texture in pak.textures {

                        //Creates texture from data and loads it into the resource for a handle
                        let texture_asset: Texture = Texture::new(Extent3d { width: 32, height: 32, depth: 1 }, TextureDimension::D2, texture.1, Rgba8UnormSrgb);

                        //This is causing problems
                        let texture_handle: Handle<Texture> = textures.add(texture_asset);

                        println!("Loading: {}", &texture.0);
                        assets.textures.insert(texture.0, texture_handle);
                        //Problems end here
                    }
                    println!("Done getting assets");
                    commands.insert_resource(assets);
                }
```

Any idea what I need to change to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

`let texture_asset: Texture = Texture::new(Extent3d { width: 32, height: 32, depth: 1 }, TextureDimension::D2, texture.1, Rgba8UnormSrgb);`

should be

`texture_asset: Texture = Texture::new(Extent3d { width: 256, height: 256, depth: 1 }, TextureDimension::D2, texture.1, Rgba8UnormSrgb);`

The difference being that the width and height must be the same as the image you're trying to load as a `Vec<u8>`, I was using a test image that was 256x256 instead of the 32x32 sprites I'm going to use.